# Can't connect through ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

I'm running two OSes, one (Backtrack 5) as a guest in VirtualBox and the other (Ubuntu 13.04) as the host. Now when I connect to my host through ssh (host-only connection):

```
$ ssh 198.168.*.* -vvv
```

I'm prompted for a password and when I enter the password I get the following error occurs:

```
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 58 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1271
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I've tried it again and again so I know that my password isn't wrong. On my host machine when I type:

```
$ ssh localhost
```

it connects normally after typing the password, but when I issue this on guest it says:

```
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
Connection closed by UNKNOWN
```

What is the problem?

edit: the first of my problem was I was trying

```
ssh ip
```

but it should be

```
ssh username@ip
```

cant connect to host though. Its refusing the connection

Comment: if possible, also post messages  of `auth.log` and `syslog`

Comment: Does anything appear in the logs on the server (`/var/log/auth.log`)? What do you have in the server configuration: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? Is there a firewall on the guest or on the host? What kind of network do you have in the VM (bridge, NAT, host-only) — can you connect from the guest to the host at all?

Comment: show the full command for ssh, what parameters you use?

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause is an expired account (which can be inspected by doing:

`chage -l`

In my case I was accessing a system that I knew worked well for many users, except for two of them.

The local file (/etc/shadow) had a bad value for the these users. Fixed by running chage interactively.

This was not evident, just a harsh "Connection closed by UNKNOWN" or a "Permission denied"  and I had no access to logs on the server side to troubleshoot. Running ssh in verbose/debug mode on the client didn't help much.